# Notify Item changed in Object Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, arrayobject

In my app, I have a horizontal gridview which is associated with an ArrayObjectAdapter. When there is a bindViewHolder call made in the presenter, I trigger for data asynchronously and update the view based on callbacks.

I want to now modify the implementation to call notifyItemChanged as manipulating the view, will cause the entire gridview to be re-drawn resulting in performance issues. Can anyone suggest how to achive recyclerview.adapter.notifyItemChanged with ArrayObjectAdapter?

Comment: I think there is no `notifyItemChanged()` method in the [`ArrayObjectAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/leanback/widget/ArrayObjectAdapter).

Answer (score 0):

In the [ArrayObjectAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/leanback/widget/ArrayObjectAdapter) you have `replace(position, item)` method which I think you can use to achieve that

Comment: Calling replace would result in notifyItemRangeChanged instead of notifyItemChanged? Unfortunately, the ListRow class in Android Jetpack library only accepts an ArrayObjectAdapter.